# asp.net VB gridview checkbox always show false on serverside code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to implement a gridview with checkbox column on asp.net (VB). when the user checks checkbox and click delete button, it should access database and delete all checked item.
I have already tried numerous googled solution and never worked for me. here is short scenario
on my aspx page:
1)search by id text box, when user enter ID and click search button, the below table is displayed

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField headertext="Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label id="namelbl" 
text='<%# Eval("name")%>' runat="server"/>
</ItemTemplate>   
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete Now?">
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox Enabled="true"   ID="chkStatus" runat="server" />

</ItemTemplate>      
</asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

after data is displayed, user checks the desired checkbox and click delete button, then the code behind is run

```
Protected Sub DelSelected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Dim idList as ArrayList = new ArrayList()
For Each row As GridViewRow In MyGridView.Rows
    Dim selectcb As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("chkStatus"), CheckBox)
     If (selectcb.Checked) Then
     'put into delete list
```

Trouble starts here, selectcb checkbox is always false
How could that happen, any idea would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must bind your data only when no IsPostback in order to persist your checkbox selected, and no reset

```
If(! IsPostBack)
{
  Bind();
}
```

Comment: If you debug your site and put breakpoints on several of your page event handler methods, this should let you see the order in which things are getting called.

Comment: umm. sorry sir, I am new to asp.net and vb, my data comes from search box and it displayed correctly. could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have read several solution about ispostback and checkbox but how can i make sure that checkbox are still checked.

Comment: Urr nevermind, Thank you so much for both of your answers. I put several breakpoints and I found that I was binding my grid even if it is postback. thanks a lot. Problem Solved